# Almighty threats!

Tags: word, wordplay, sequence, anagram, word-sequence

There's rhyme and reason behind the following 10-step sequence of words and phrases:

> 1. HUSK
> 2. BE COMELY
>
> 3. TRACKED
> 4. NOT HOOK
>
> 5. KICK TIPS
> 6. CUSP
>
> 7. ALMIGHTY
> 8. THREATS
>
> 9. BEFIT
> 10. ?

**The name of which country could replace the question mark above?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nice puzzle. The country that could replace the question mark is:

> **GHANA**

Because:

> Each pair of words and phrases are an anagram from the nursery rhyme **ONE TWO BUCKLE MY SHOE** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One,_Two,_Buckle_My_Shoe)

HUSK & BE COMELY =

> BUCKLE MY SHOE ( 1, 2 BUCKLE MY SHOE)

TRACKED & NOT HOOK =

> KNOCK AT THE DOOR ( 3. 4 KNOCK AT THE DOOR)

KICK TIPS & CUSP =

> PICK UP STICKS (5, 6 PICK UP STICKS)

ALMIGHTY THREATS =

> LAY THEM STRAIGHT (7, 8 LAY THEM STRAIGHT)

which leaves BEFIT =

> A BIG FAT HEN (9, 10 A BIG FAT HEN) - The remaining letters after removing 'BEFIT'  from 'A BIG FAT HEN' are AGAHN - which is an anagram of **GHANA**

The title =

> is an anagram of LAY THEM STRAIGHT, confirming the need to rearrange the words into the correct order

Comment: A perfect answer - well done :)

Comment: rot13(Gurer'f n "eulzr" naq ernfba)... very nice